# Actualizar tabla con jquery, ajax, php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
estamos en un proyecto de registro de mascotas, tenemos un nuevo problema, que al momento de dar click en guardar se debe de actualizar en la base de datos, el estado y las observaciones, lo estamos haciendo en Ajax y php, le dejamos, gracias, somos nuevos en programación por eso pedimos su ayuda,

```
  <form class="" action="index.html" method="post">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Estado</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="estadoSolicitud" name="estaSolicitud">
                <?php
                    $sqlestado = "SELECT * FROM estado";
                        $consultaEstado = $conexion->query($sqlestado);
                           while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($consultaEstado)) {
                                                echo "<option value='" .
                                                    $valores['idestado'] .
                                                    "'>" .
                                                    $valores['estado'] .
                                                    "</option>";
                                            }
                                            ?>
               </select>
           </div>
     </div>

<div class="row">
     <div class="col">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="observacionesRegistra">Observaciones</label>
             <textarea class="form-control" id="observacionesRegistra" rows="3" name="observacion"></textarea>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Bodigo donde se llama a la función

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#guardarSolicitud").click(function() {
actualizaDatoss();
    });
 });
```

Función

```
function actualizaDatoss() {
solicitud = $("#estadoSolicitud").val();
 obs = $("#observacionesRegistra").val();

cadena = "&solicitud=" + solicitud + "&obs=" + obs;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../pages/tables/update.php",
data: cadena,
success: function(r) {}
  });
 }
```

Código php

```
<?php
 include_once '../../../includes/templates/conexion.php';
 $idestado = $_POST['idestado'];
$estaSolicitud = $_POST['estaSolicitud'];
$observacion = $_POST['observacion'];

 $sqlupdate = "UPDATE solicitud set idestado='$estaSolicitud', 
 observaciones='$observacion' where idestado='$idestado'";

$ejecutar = mysqli_query($conexion, $sqlupdate);
?>
```

Comment: Tienes problema en los `$_POST`, si  estás enviando esto al servidor: `cadena = "&solicitud=" + solicitud + "&obs=" + obs;` tienes que poner los `$_POST` de este modo: `$estaSolicitud = $_POST['solicitud'];
$observacion = $_POST['obs'];` hay otro valor que intentas recuperar: `$idestado = $_POST['idestado'];` pero no lo estás pasando desde Ajax. También puedes pasar en `data` un objeto, es más claro así: `cadena = {solicitud: solicitud , obs: obs};` ahí el valor de la izquierda es el índice y el de la derecha es el dato.

Comment: Serias tan amable de explicarnos un poco mas

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores en el código.

Cuando envías algo vía Ajax, usas el parámetro `data` como bien haces aquí:

```
data: cadena,
```

Luego en el servidor recuperarás esa información con `$_POST` u otro según el caso...

La notación es la siguiente: `$_POST['clave']` donde `clave` equivale al dato que pusiste a la izquierda.

Si escribiste `cadena` así:

```
cadena = "&solicitud=" + solicitud + "&obs=" + obs;
```

Significa que en el `$_POST` habrá dos claves: `solicitud` y `obs` y que para recuperarlo tienes que hacerlo así:

```
$estaSolicitud = $_POST['solicitud'];
$observacion = $_POST['obs'];
```

Pero estás usando las claves mal:

```
$estaSolicitud = $_POST['estaSolicitud'];
$observacion = $_POST['observacion'];
```

porque `$_POST` no tiene una clave `estaSolicitud` ni una clave `observacion`.

---

Otro posible error es en la URL:

```
url: "../pages/tables/update.php",
```

No estoy seguro si debas ponerlo así:

```
url: "../pages/tables/update.php?",
```

dado que estás enviando los datos en forma de cadena... es algo que no he probado. De todos modos, es mejor mandar un objeto, es mucho más claro así.

Pon la petición Ajax de este modo:

```
function actualizaDatoss() {
  solicitud = $("#estadoSolicitud").val();
  obs = $("#observacionesRegistra").val();
  datos = {solicitud: solicitud, obs: obs};

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "../pages/tables/update.php",
   data: datos,
   success: function(r) { console.log(r) }
  });
}
```

---

Otro error es que intentas recuperar esto:

```
 $idestado = $_POST['idestado'];
```

Pero desde Ajax no mandas ninguna clave `idestado` por tanto ese valor no lo encontrará.